# panel regression with lm and factor, data 'leaking' across panels or groups

Tags: r, lm

I'm trying to run a panel regression with this sample data, however it looks like some data is 'leaking' across groups:

```
data = data.frame(group = c('a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c'), 
                  var1 = c(10, 8, 5, 7, 9, 0, 3, 2, 9))
ft = lm(var1 ~ I(dplyr::lag(var1, 1)) + factor(group), data = data)
ft$model
  var1 I(dplyr::lag(var1, 1)) factor(group)
2    8                     10             a
3    5                      8             a
4    7                      5             b
5    9                      7             b
6    0                      9             b
7    3                      0             c
8    2                      3             c
9    9                      2             c
```

In the fitted data it shows that some data has shifted groups, the edge cases. Lagging by 1 per group I would expect two observations per group, discarding the first, however groups 'b' and 'c' have three observations.

How do I prevent this leaking and have it lagging by group? Expected `ft$model` would be something like:

```
  group    var1          `lag(var1, 1)`
1 a        10             NA
2 a         8             10
3 a         5              8
4 b         7             NA
5 b         9              7
6 b         0              9
7 c         3             NA
8 c         2              3
9 c         9              2
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not first create the data that we want and then apply it to `lm` ?

```
data %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(lag_var1 = lag(var1)) -> data1

#  group  var1 lag_var1
#  <chr> <dbl>    <dbl>
#1 a        10       NA
#2 a         8       10
#3 a         5        8
#4 b         7       NA
#5 b         9        7
#6 b         0        9
#7 c         3       NA
#8 c         2        3
#9 c         9        2
```